# Laravel won't send email to multi receiver

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send multi email but it returning such errors:

> Expected response code 354 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.0
>   Requested action not taken: too many emails per second"

## Code

```
$reciverss = array_merge($admins, $workers); // finalizing my queries and joining two arrays in one

// getting input data
$details = array(
  'body' => $request->input('body'),
  'subject' => $request->input('subject'),
);

// getting receivers email addresses from my merged array and try to send input data to them as email
foreach($reciverss as $receive){
  Mail::to($receive->email)->send(new PICMAIL($details));
}
```

#### More

Here is how my data of `$rereciverss` looks like:

```
[{email: "admin@admin.com", username: "admin", userId: 1},…]
  0: {email: "admin@admin.com", username: "admin", userId: 1}
  1: {email: "employee@employee.com", username: "employee", userId: 2}
  2: {email: "non-employee@employee.com", username: "non employee", userId: 3}
```

Basically I need to get emails out to send them email but it returning error I mentioned above.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your error says

> too many emails per second

you can add some delay in the emails and try it again or use [Job throttling](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#rate-limiting) to handle this case. 
have a look at the [sleep()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function

```
foreach($reciverss as $receive){
  sleep(30);
  Mail::to($receive->email)->send(new PICMAIL($details));
}
```

Comment: `30` is what? second??

Comment: @mafortis yes, but this number depends on the email service you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
#emails=[];
foreach($reciverss as $receive){
  sleep(30);
  $emails[]=$receive->email;
}
if(count($emails)){
  Mail::to($emails)->send(new PICMAIL($details));
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of validating emails but it sends emails header like `To: <employee@employee.com, non-employee@employee.com>` not my favorite to share users emails to each other.

Comment: Doesn't this just delay adding new emails to the `$emails` array, but then sends them all in one go?

Comment: yes delay is working now by sleep but if i use `$emails[]` it sends email of all users at once what i prefer is to each user only see their own email see here to get my point https://ibb.co/vs0kzz9

Answer (score 0):

use a queue is the best decision here & Dispatch that.

```
foreach($reciverss as $receive){

  MailQueueClass::dispatch(with_your_data);

}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Email;

use App\Mail\InvoiceCreated;
use App\Models\Order\Order;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Mail;

class SendInvoice implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private your_variable;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param $order_id
     */
    public function __construct($your_variable1,$your_variable2)
    {
        $this->your_variable1 = $your_variable1;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       Mail::to($your_variable1)->send(new PICMAIL($your_variable2));
    }
}
```

for details https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues

Comment: The queue worker could still run the jobs too quickly for the email service.